# accessing data in template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

When using `{{#each}}` in a template, I have to use `{{this.name}} - {{this.thing}}` instead of just `{{name}} - {{thing}}` for some reason.

`{{thing}}` prints out the proper value, but `{{name}}` is just a copy of `{{thing}}` instead of actually printing the correct value.

If I use `{{this.name}}`, the correct value is returned.

```
template.html
<template name="templ">
{{#each items}}
    {{name}} - {{thing}}<br/> // name == thing unless i use this.name/this.thing
{{/each}}
</template>


template.js
Template.templ.helpers({
    'items':function(){
        return Items.find(); //also tried find().fetch()
    }
});
```

**EDIT console output of Items.find().fetch()**

    `[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
    0:{
        Object_id: "er2KGErydGoZBwrMc",
        name: "A",
        thing: "b.txt"
    },
    1:{
        Object_id: "vmkgkejA3TvLZu6c6",
        name: "B",
        thing: "b.txt"
    },
    2:{
        Object_id: "jzA2szPiakXiLibCq",
        name: "C",
        thing: "c.txt"
    },
    3: {
        Object_id: "RA29CJkgZHmhreWZo",
        name: "E",
        thing: "e.txt"
    }`

Using just {{name}} - {{thing}} in {{#each}} block renders value of thing for each item. {{this.name}} renders correct value for name.

Comment: What does the data structure look like when you do a console.log(Items.find().fetch());  ? Can you copy and paste it here so I can help debug?

Comment: Your helper function name is "items" and you're doing an each on "item" instead of "items" (with an 'S'). Can you check if that's the syntax error just to be sure?

Comment: Yes, not a typo in my actual code. And I just noticed before the console output, it prints a blank array as well `[]`. Seems to be logging twice from that one helper. First without data, then with the data.

Comment: Try throwing a `debugger;` line in the helper function to check the call stack and how many times it gets called. Also try renaming the helper and each to something less generic since it might be called elsewhere in your code. Just make sure you're positive the issue is isolated.

Comment: I put the same code for the template and helper in a different template/helper and it works fine. I'll try renaming the helper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71634/discussion-between-eric-shell-and-eric-t).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a helper already named {{name}}. So {{#each}} {{name}}-{{thing}} {{/each}} was using the name helper instead of the data context.

oops